# List view showing error on scroll custom adapter

Tags: android, listview

I am using a Custom Adapter, to show list view but unfortunately when ever I scroll it is showing a null object reference.

I have looked at previous asked questions, but nothing worked anysuggestions?

Screenshot:

![enter image description here][1]

09-09 13:39:53.949 3111-3111/com.aug22.avinashchintareddy.ecommerce E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.aug22.avinashchintareddy.ecommerce, PID: 3111
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.aug22.avinashchintareddy.ecommerce.adapters.ProductAdapt.getView(ProductAdapt.java:79)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:666)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5029)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3424)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3820)
                                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3651)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9294)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)

This is error Log

My adapter class
    enter code here

in side get view added log to check what's happening but unfortunately when ever the list is scrolled the rendering elements are shown but not all of the elements 
also you can see the log added at getting view size.
Adapter class.

```
         public class ProductAdapt
        extends BaseAdapter {
        List 
        productAcessorList ;
        Context context;
         LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
         setClicker clicker;

          public ProductAdapt(List
                 productAcessorList, Context context) {
            this.productAcessorList = productAcessorList;
            this.context = context;
            layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {

            Log.i("List size",""+
            productAcessorList.size());
            return productAcessorList.size();
                }

            @Override
            public Object 
            getItem(int i) {
             return i;
                }

         @Override
         public long getItemId(int i) {
           return i;
             }

            public static class Handler{
            TextView tx_prodname,
            tx_proddesc,tx_proid;
            ImageView img_prd;

            }

          @Override
            public View getView(final int i, 
            View myview, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            if(myview == null){
              myview=layoutInflater.inflate
              (R.layout.list_prod,viewGroup,false);
              handler.tx_prodname=(TextView) 
              myview.findViewById(R.id.txt_categid);
              handler.tx_proddesc=(TextView) 
              myview.findViewById(R.id.txt_descid);
              handler.tx_proid=(TextView) 
              myview.findViewById(R.id.txt_idi);
              handler.img_prd=myview.
              findViewById(R.id.img_view);

                myview.setTag(handler);
             }
            else
            {
              myview.getTag();

            }

            Log.i("find fault",""+
            productAcessorList.get(i).getProduct());

          handler.tx_prodname.
          setText(""+productAcessorList.get(i).getProduct());
          handler.tx_proddesc.
          setText(""+productAcessorList.get(i).getDescrip());
          handler.tx_proid.
          setText(""+productAcessorList.get(i).getId());
          Picasso.with(context).
          load(""+productAcessorList.
          get(i).getImage()).
          into(handler.img_prd);
           myview.
           setOnClickListener
           (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if(clicker!=null){
                    clicker.gotClick(view,i);

                }

                }
             });

            return myview;
         }


         public void getClicker
            (setClicker clicker){
          this.clicker=clicker;

            }

            }
```

Comment: Plaese post your error log as text not as an image and format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
myview.getTag();
```

you should have

```
handler = (Handler) myview.getTag();
```

By the way, usually such class is called `Holder` or `ViewHolder`. It saves you from repeating time consuming tasks like `findViewById()` calls in every getView call.

For every new item view you create a view holder and fill it. Then you set it as the view tag. It's ok. This all is done to be able later to fetch this tag and use it as view holder. But in your code you never used the tag, instead you were accessing an empty holder instance with null fields.

Comment: Woow algrid it's working but I had similar list view used previously it was working for that. Can  you explain I need to refer handler over here.

Comment: @avinashreddychintareddy added a bit of explanation